# Django automatically changes camel case

Tags: python-3.x, django, database-migration

I am using models.IntegerChoices as Enum in Django, but it is saved in DB in a changed way.

```
class FruitsEnum(models.IntegerChoices):
    Apple = 1
    RedApple = 2
    GreenApple = 3
    LongBanana = 4
    DragonFruit = 5
```

But it is saved in database like this : [('0','Apple'),('1','Redapple'),('2','Greenapple')...]

As you see the word 'apple' is not uppercase in two-word combinations. How Can I achive this :
[('0','Apple'),('1','Red**Apple**'),('2','Green**Apple**')...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing integers, just pass a tuple consisting of the integer and the related name. Something like:

```py
class FruitsEnum(models.IntegerChoices):
    Apple = 1, 'Apple'
    RedApple = 2, 'RedApple'
    GreenApple = 3, 'GreenApple'
    LongBanana = 4, 'LongBanana'
    DragonFruit = 5, 'DragonFruit'
```

Alternatively, within your model, in the `IntegerField` where you're using this, you can replace `FruitsEnum.choices` with a tuple like:

```py
[(1,'Apple'),(2,'RedApple'),(3,'GreenApple'),(4,'LongBanana'),(5,'DragonFruit')]
```

**Note:** Any differences you observe here are purely cosmetic and does not exist outside django (i.e within the database). You can open the database directly and see that only the integers are stored in the table.